# Привязка высоты DIV

Tags: html, css

Вот есть код:

```
<div style="width:5px;"><div>
<div>текст<br>еще текст<div>
```

Можно ка-кто на css привязать высоту первого div к второму?

Answer (score 1):

Классы как раз для этого и были придуманы. Правда в вашем случае простым width не обойтись, придется определять div ни как блочный элемент, а ячейку таблицы, тогда можно будет определить высоту элемента в абсолютных значениях.

Comment: Мысль использовать таблицу была, во все же хотелось бы на диве сделать.

Comment: Ты не так понял. Нужно использовать те де div, но переопределенные как ячейки таблицы через свойство css display: table-cell. Почитай вот здесь http://htmlbook.ru/css/display

Comment: И еще здесь http://htmlbook.ru/blog/div-nye-kolonki-odinakovoy-vysoty-na-css